# How to achieve precise CSS rendering?

Tags: css, precision

I have one div with primitive styles

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
border-radius: 50%;
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: solid 1px #cfcfcf;
```

and `:after` pseudoelement on it

```
content: '';
display: flex;
width: 14px;
height: 14px;
background: #3fcaca;
border-radius: 50%;
```

But such divs look different in the different screen area. Browser zoom is 100%

I am using 15 inch full HD screen with windows up-scaling which obviously is the reason. Is there a way to fix such things by some CSS adjustments?

[image]

Comment: It is difficult to center objects with even numbers. Try changing to odd numbers so there is a clear center of the size.15px and 17 px.

Comment: This is a valid way to do this, but couldn't you simply apply the border to the pseudo-element instead of it's parent?

Comment: If it is to be a static image, adding the border would work well, if they are separate for visual effect like the teal one moving on button press, then they have to remain separate. We don't know the OPs intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very simple answer:

Just replace `border` with `box-shadow`. Sounds unusual, but box-shadow can generate absolutely same look as border and in same time looks always smooth. Even on pixel-scaled screens

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align things on top of an element with `:after` (or `before:`), set the parent element to `position: relative;` then set the `:after` to `position: absolute;`, then adjust `top:`, `left:`, to make things line up.